# sorting in cuda Thrust

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to use radix sort in the cuda. During research I found that thrust has the sorting feature in it.

```
which sorting algorithm does thrust library use for sorting?? 
Is it  Radix Sort???
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find some details here:

http://sbel.wisc.edu/Courses/ME964/Literature/thrustGPUgems2011.pdf
http://www.greatlakesconsortium.org/events/manycore/files/TStaff-CUDA_Libraries.pdf

From the second link:

> thrust::sort will select right algorithm
>
> - radix sort for built-in types(int, float, etc.)
> - merge sort where radix sort cannot be used

For an even deeper understanding of the thrust implementation of the sort function you should read this technical paper: http://back40computing.googlecode.com/svn-history/r272/wiki/documents/RadixSortTR.pdf

Answer (score 0):

One of the two sorting algorithms Thrust provides is Radix Sort.